# Обработка сложного объекта по http get в Angular 6

Tags: typescript, httpclient, angular5, rxjs, angular

народ, я не понимаю, как обработать объект, на который я подписываюсь. Объект представляет собой следующую структуру:

```
    {
      data:{
           date: "2018-02-20 13:10:23",
           text: "Описание",
           id: 1,
           items: [
                  0: {
                     date: "2018-02-20 13:10:23",
                     text: "Описание",
                     images: [
                             0: "image1.jpg",
                             1: "image2.jpg"
                             ],
                     name: "Изображения",
                     type: "images"
                     },
                  1: {
                     date: "2018-02-20 13:10:23",
                     text: "Описание",
                     image: null,
                     type: "video",
                     url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/v64KOxKVLVg"
                     }
                  ]
           }
    }
```

Обращение делаю через сервис:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class VideoService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getVideoTape() {
        return this.http.get(`http://ip_adress/api/v1/mixed_galleries/1`);
    }
}
```

Есть интерфейсная модель:

```
export class VideoListModel {
    constructor(
        public created_at: string,
        public description: string,
        public id: number,
        public items: any[],
        public name: string
    ) {}
}
```

А обработку делаю в компоненте:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {VideoService} from '../shared/services/video.service';
import {VideoListModel} from '../../shared/models/video-list.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-index',
  templateUrl: './video-index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-index.component.scss']
})

export class VideoIndexComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private videoTape = [];
    private _subscription2: Subscription;

    constructor( private videoService: VideoService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this._subscription2 = this.videoService.getVideoTape()
          .subscribe((data: VideoListModel[]) => {
          this.videoTape = data;
          console.log(this.videoTape);
      });
  }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this._subscription2.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

А задача у меня сделать выборку из объектов по type: "video". Через AJAX+jQuery делал это без проблем, а в Angular я относительно новичок. Перелопатил вчера кучу видео-уроков, но нигде не представлены примеры фильтрации таких сложных объектов.

Конструкция типа:

```
this._subscription2 = this.videoService.getVideoTape()
          .pipe(filter((data: VideoListModel[]) => data.items.type === 'video'))
          .subscribe((data: any) => {
              this.videoTape = data.data;
              console.log(this.videoTape);
          });
```

Результатом дает ошибку, мол "Property 'items' does not exist on type 'VideoListModel[]'". Интуитивно я понимаю, что дело скорее всего в интерфейсе, но не могу понять, как интерфейс доработать, чтобы фильтрация работала корректно. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с фильтрацией сложносоставных объектов, подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка вполне логичная, `data.items` это массив, у него нет свойства `type`, оно есть у **элементов** этого массива. Соответственно внутри `subscribe` без всякой магии фильтруете все что не нужно.

```
if (data && data.items) {
    let i = data.items.length;
    while(i--) {
        if (data.items[i].type != 'video') {
            data.items.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    this.videoTape = data;
}
```

Старайтесь как можно точнее описывать модель данных, чем меньше `any` тем больше шансов что компилятор заметит ошибку, для того собственно типизация в typescript'е и нужна...